Default address for unlink in laravel
To update a record with a photo, I have used the unlink command to delete the photo in the corresponding directory. I have already saved the file name and path separately in the database and to delete the file, I have written it as follows:
unlink($task->FilePath.$task->TaskFile);

but return this error:
unlink(/assets/TaskFiles/2024/04/921308991.png): No such file or directory

Considering that my default address is the public branch on the server, how do I add the default address to be placed at the beginning of the address?

Does this answer your question? How to delete file from public folder in laravel 5.1

You'll need to use the public_path function to get the full file path starting from the public directory
unlink(public_path($task->FilePath.$task->TaskFile));


You can use the Storage facade to handle file operations. Here's how you can delete a file using the Storage facade in Laravel
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
$filePath = $task->FilePath . $task->TaskFile;

// Check if the file exists before attempting to delete it
if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($filePath)) {
    // Delete the file
    Storage::disk('public')->delete($filePath);
} else {
    // File does not exist
    // Handle the case where the file doesn't exist, or log an error
}

